# Invalid JPEG file structure: two SOI markers error?

Tags: java, sockets, jpeg

[This is the image that causes an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUvEW.jpg)

I have this problem and I tried everything I know but nothing worked. 
I'm trying to send  multiple images (one image at time) from a database to client application  through socket, sometimes everything works just fine, but sometimes it declare this "invalid  JPEG file structure: two SOI markers" error?

client side :

```
for(User user : users){
    int cmpt=0;

    byteToread =in.readInt();
    bytesOut=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(bytesOut);    

    while (byteToread >cmpt) {
        cmpt = in.read(dataEntre);
        bos.write(dataEntre, 0, cmpt);
        bos.flush();
        byteToread-=cmpt;
    } 
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesOut.toByteArray()));

    user.setPhoto(new ImageIcon(bi));
    System.out.println("------------------end");
}
bos.close();
bytesOut.close();
```

server side :

```
InputStream input =null;

Statement myStmt = null;
ResultSet myRs = null;
BufferedInputStream bis=null;
try {
    myStmt = Conn.createStatement();
    myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select Photo from users order by Name");
    byte[] buffer; 

    int k =1;

    while (myRs.next()) {
        input=myRs.getBinaryStream("Photo");
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(input);
        buffer = new byte[1024];

        try {
            int byteToread = 0;
            int cmpt=0;

            byteToread=input.available();
            out.writeInt(byteToread);
            out.flush(); 

            int i=0;  
            while (byteToread>cmpt) {
                cmpt = bis.read(buffer);
                out.write(buffer, 0, cmpt);
                out.flush();
                byteToread -= cmpt;
            } 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this problem just appeared recently , my application worked for almost 2 months correctly , but now this error from nowhere

Comment: It could be that for 2 months the images you used didn't trigger the issue. 
It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Also recommend linking an image that causes this to fail in case someone wants to test this out themselves. (assuming ofcourse the image is not copyrighted)

Comment: well ,  i will thank you , so what about the code did i write it right , specially the client side

Comment: Where is the SOI markers appearing in the stream? Have you run some JPEG dumping program to find the market ordering?

Comment: The image can be read perfectly fine using `ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/your/file.jpg"))` (and there's only a single SOI marker, as it should have). So the error is in your byte shuffling code, as both EJP and JoeBlade have pointed out...

Comment: ok , i fixed the problem thank you

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `available()` as a measure of the length of the input. There is a specific warning in the Javadoc against that. That's not what it's for.

Your copy loops should look like this:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First things first:
the error you encounter:

each JPEG image *always* starts with a StartOfImage marker which in hex is: FFD8
The bytes in the buffer you are creating contain this SOI marker twice. 
It is very likely that you are getting the bytes of image 1 + some bytes of image2, in particular the starting bytes that contain the marker of the second image.

I think you are making a mistake here:

```
byteToread =in.readInt();
bytesOut=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(bytesOut);     
while (byteToread >cmpt) {
    cmpt = in.read(dataEntre);
    bos.write(dataEntre, 0, cmpt);
    bos.flush();
    byteToread-=cmpt;
}
```

take for instance a situation where you have a total of 100 bytes.
for some reason you will read these 100 bytes in chunks of 50, 30, 20 bytes.

this will give the following:

```
iteration 1:
during while:   
    bytesToRead: 100
    cmpt: 0
at the end of the loop:
    bytesToRead: 50
    cmpt: 50
iteration 2:
during while:   
    bytesToRead: 50
    cmpt: 50
```

at this point, byteToRead (50) is not > than cmpt (50) so the loop ends while you don't write the last 50 bytes.

you probably need something like:

```
bytesToread = in.readInt();
bytesOut=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(bytesOut);     
while (byteToread > 0) {
    cmpt = in.read(dataEntre);
    bos.write(dataEntre, 0, cmpt);
    bos.flush();
    byteToread-=cmpt;
}
```

Probably with small images you'll read the entire amount of bytes in one go (though this isn't guaranteed, but just likely). If this happens then you'll finish in one iteration and never encounter the problem. But with larger images you risk that the last chunk you read causes you to miss some bytes at the end of your image. and this can cause trouble (I think)

A second issue could be (on serverside)

```
byteToread=input.available();
```

The resultset you get from the db might not have all the bytes available for you to use yet.

from the documentation of available()

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

From what I can see that's going wrong (and based on my testing program) the following occurs:

1: you get image1 (say 200 bytes).
2: you write length (200) to your output stream
3: you write less than 200 bytes to the output stream (say 150). (because of faulty logic)
4: you get image2 (say 300 bytes)
5: you write length (300) to your output stream
6: you write N bytes to the output stream.

when you read

1: you read image1.length. this returns you 200.
2: you read 200 bytes. because you only wrote 150 bytes from image 1, this means you get 150 bytes from image1, length of image2 and then 46 bytes from image2.

this results in the bytes you think are image 1 containing 2 headers for the jpg. (the first 46 bytes of image2 will contain the header for image2 afterall)

I think you need to attach your debugger and step through this and find out what else is going wrong. the other answer given shows how to loop through and count your read bytes properly. There may be more issues.

Comment: yeah i i did  that too  but  like you said it causes to miss some bytes , the code i write i does  work the most of the  time but in sometimes it doesn't  ,

Comment: In my answer I explained why (I think) it sometimes works and other times doesn't. You cannot control how many bytes your application reads at any time. try using the while (byteToRead > 0) and see if it works better.

Comment: i did , and the server do send every images and every byte  and the client app do not declare any error  , but the execution do not continue to next step or next instructions  , it's  like  the input socket still waiting for more data but the server already send every and move forward

Comment: Actually on rereading you make this mistake both on clientside and serverside. Both sides you should use while (bytesToread > 0) instead of bytesToRead > compt

Comment: yes i used while(bytesToread>0) to both sides  , it doesn't declare any error but like i said the clientside do not continue the execution , and do not stop either , it's like stiil  waiting  data from the server

Comment: I'll try to get this into a working program that I can run locally. I'll let you know. (I'll avoid the database but the rest I'll try to keep the same)